# How do I make $watch react on a scope variable change in a unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a unit test for a controller that watches a variable on its scope. When I change the variable's value, the $watch isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this in your test should make sure it is updated:

```
it('should update watched value', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.yourWatchedVariable = 'new value';
    });
    //expect something to happen based on watch
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $apply() on the scope.

$watch evaluates the watched variable on each digest cycle, but in a unit test digest isn't run continuously - you have to invoke it yourself by calling $apply or $digest.